# Adding SSL to Spring Boot Application which will be deployed on Kubernates engine in GCP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress

I have the requirement of adding SSL certificates to the spring boot application. I need to use these certificates a make a request to an web service.  I have multiple certificates that should be added to my application.

So my question is: how do you add such certificates to a Spring boot application and how will the JVM know to use that particular web service call?

If you add this certificates to JVM how you will be adding those certificates to kubernetes engine this is where we are planning to deploy the application in QA and PROD.

Comment: thank you formatting the question